# My protocol definition is not visible in another Swift file

Tags: swift, protocols

I have two files: `DBStartViewController.swift` and `DBFindViewController.swift`

when I define my `protocol`:

```
protocol DBViewAnimationTransitioning {
    var viewForAnimation: UIView? { get set }
}
```

in `DBStartViewController.swift` it is not visible in my `DBFindViewController.swift`. I get an error:

> Use of undeclared type `DBViewAnimationTransitioning`.

But when I move my declaration to `DBFindViewController.swift` then everything is ok. Why it works like that?

I need to have it in my `DBStartViewController.swift` to make my code clean and clear.

Comment: Are `DBStartViewController` and `DBFindViewController` in the same app target? If either of them are in an embedded framework, for example, you might need to use the `public` access modifier for your protocol.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your prompt:-) It was because `DBStartViewController` wasn't in the test target like it was with `DBFindViewController`. I just checked to add my `DBStartViewController` to the test target and everything was ok.

Comment: I'll add it as an aswer, if you don't mind. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your classes reside in separate app targets, make sure you use `public` as an access modifier for your protocol. By default it's `internal`, which means it's shared within the module, but not visible from the outside.

Comment: Sometimes when compiler shows an error we do not know what target it is concerned. In this case we need to jump to `project navigator` -> `issue navigator`, and then we can see where is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `Target Membership` on the right-side bar is properly checked when your protocol is selected/opened.

Answer (score -2):

You might have the protocol declaration inside your ViewController class. In that case you might need to call `DBStartViewController.DBViewAnimationTransitioning`.

To be sure, I would need to see a little more of the code.